# Struggling to solve $\ w^2 + 2iw = i \ $

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

I'm struggling to solve: $\ w^2 + 2iw = i \ $ 
I substituted $\ w = x+iy \ $, and eventually got these two equations:
$\ x^2 - y^2 = 2y \ $ and $\ 2xy = 1-2x \ $.
I'm not quite sure where to go from here. I've tried using $\ x^2 = y^2 + 2y \ $,
but I just end up in a dead situation. Can somebody help, please?
Thanks

Comment: $w^2 + 2iw - i = 0$ and then use the quadratic formula

Comment: Welcome to MSE: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: Yes I do, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the equation $$2xy+2x-1=0$$ we obtain
$$y=\frac{1-2x}{2x}$$ plug this in your first equation
doing this we get
$$4x^4+4x^2-1=0$$

Comment: Is it supposed to be -2x on your second line of working out (the numerator)?

Comment: from $$2xy+x-1=0$$ we get $$y=\frac{1-x}{2x}$$

Comment: But isn't it 2xy + 2x -1?

Comment: that is correct, just corrected, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is a quadratic equation. Apply the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

Write as:

$$\begin{align}
w^2 +2iw-1 &= i-1 = e^{i 3\pi/4 } \\
 (w+i)^2 &= e^{i 3\pi/4 }
\end{align}$$

So we get solution as: $-i \pm e^{i3\pi / 8}$ which may be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Note that we have: $$F(w): w^2 +2iw-i=0$$ Note that we can solve this quadratic in $w$ using the quadratic formula, just as we do it using real numbers.

We thus get: $$w = \frac{ - 2i \pm \sqrt{-4+4i}}{2}$$ $$= - i \pm \sqrt{i-1}$$ as our solutions.